# SelectionSort and InsertionSort

Tags: sorting

I have to answer the following question: Could you think of a scenario in which SelectionSort is better (in terms of the development of the result) than InsertionSort.

My idea is that if you only need e.g. the top 10 of a very big list, your could end the sorting after the 10th step. Is this a valid answer to this question? Could you think of other scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When input array is "close to sorted" selecion sort have better performance than insertion sort. Also there are two things you must take in mind: selection sort needs only Θ(n) swaps versus Ο(n2) (in case of insertion sort) swaps; selection sort has stability strong realization, insertion sort has no.

Comment: common selection sort is NOT stable, but insertion sort is

Comment: for selection sort, even a perfectly sorted input requires scanning the entire array => `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 2):

InsertionSort has `Ο(n^2)` swaps in worst case, but SelectionSort is `Θ(n)`. So if writes are significantly more expensive than reads, SelectionSort is better suited.